# Check length of a String in Android

Tags: android, string

I want to check whether the entered strings length is between 3 to 8 characters. Previously I used `if condition` and it worked. However when I introduced some substring from the string , one of the `if statements` doesnt work. Can some one help me to understand why. Thanks.

My codes is

Working Code:

```
   text = et.getText().toString();
    l = text.length();
    a = text.substring(0, 1);
    if (l >=9) tv.setText("Invalid length!!! Please check your code");
    if (l <= 2) tv.setText("Invalid length! Please check your code");
```

And here, the second `if statement doesnt` work.

```
text = et.getText().toString();
l = text.length();
a = text.substring(0, 1);
c = text.substring(1, 2);
d = text.substring(3, 4);
e = text.substring(4);
if (l >=9) tv.setText("Invalid length!!! Please check your code");
if (l <= 2) tv.setText("Invalid length! Please check your code");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will want to ensure that you handle a null string as well as ensuring your string is within the limits you want.  consider:

```
text = et.getText().toString();
if (text == null || text.length() < 3 || text.length > 8) {
    tv.setText("Invalid length, should be from 3 to 8 characters. Please check your code");
} else {
    a = text.substring(0,1);
    b = text.substring(1,2);

    c = text.substring(3,4);
    if (text.length() > 3) {
      d = text.substring(4);
    } else {
         d = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the length before trying to create substrings, since if the length is too short the substring indexes are invalid. Try this:

```
text = et.getText().toString();
l = text.length();
if (l >= 9 || l <= 2) {
    tv.setText("Invalid length!!! Please check your code");
} else {
    a = text.substring(0, 1);
    c = text.substring(1, 2);
    d = text.substring(3, 4);
    e = text.substring(4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. What I dont understand is that Im trying to check the length of the original string and how creating substrings affect that. Sorry for asking too many questions. Im new to Java/Android programming.

Comment: @AUJ - If the original string is too short, then some of the calls to `substring` may throw an exception. For instance, if the string is "Hi", then trying to execute `c = text.substring(1,2)` will attempt to access the 3rd character, which doesn't exist. That's why you need to avoid making those calls when the length check indicates a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ted. This saved me lot of time. I was struggling with this for hours:(

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

> **editText.getText().toString().length() < 3**

```
EditText etmobile_no;

if (etmobile_no.getText().toString("") || 
etmobile_no.getText().toString().length() <3 ||
 etmobile_no.getText().toString().length() >8)

{
    tv.setText("Invalid length, should be from 3 to 8 characters. Please check your code");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good solution:

```
fun styleLimitedText(text: String, length: Int): String {
    if (text.length > length) return text.substring(0, length) + "..."
    return text
}
```